# Excluding item from Pivot Table filter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am new in VBA and I'm developing a code in which I would like to add all items to a pivot table filter, excluding only code "01" every time.

```
pt6.PivotFields("[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].[something_here456]").visibleItemsList = Array( _
  "[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].&[02]", _
  "[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].&[03]", _
  "[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].&[04]", _
  "[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].&[06]", _
  "[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].&[07]", _
  "[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].&[NULL]")
```

The problem with this code is that when I apply this code to another file, one of the items (e.g. "06") may not exist, and the code breaks. So I would like to have something that only excludes 01 and activates everything else. I tried everything I saw online, like "Visible = False", but it still gives me an error. Please help me my friends

Also tried, for example:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("something_here456). _
   CurrentPage = "(ALL)"

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("something_here456")
   .PivotItems("01").Visible = False

End with
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the Pivot Items and set everything to visible except the `01` with something like

```
Dim pvtItem As PivotItem

For Each pvtItem In PT6.PivotFields("[Data Pull  2].[something_here456].[something_here456]").PivotItems
   If pvtItem.Caption <> "01" Then
       pvtItem.Visible = True
   Else
       pvtItem.Visible = False 
   End If
Next pvtItem
```

Comment: It seems that for OLAP data sources the Caption property of the PivotItem object returns a null string.  Also, the Visible property  seems to be read only, so you'll get an error when trying to set it to True or False.

Comment: I tried that code. The code runs but 01 remains selected

Comment: It probably falls inline with @Domenic reply above. I would step through the code and see if it returns a `null` value for `pvtItem.caption`